# Logical AND, OR: Is left-to-right evaluation guaranteed?

Tags: c++, logical-operators, operator-precedence, short-circuiting

Is left-to-right evaluation of logical operators (`&&` `||`) guaranteed?

Let's say I have this:

```
SDL_Event event;

if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            // do stuff
    }
}
```

Is this guaranteed to be the same as this?

```
SDL_Event event;

if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This can also be very important, let's say we have two requirements, `a` and `b`. Requirement `a` is much more likely to fail then `b`. Then it's more efficient to say `if (a && b)` than `if (b && a)`.

Comment: A classic, important use for the sequencing implied by `&&` is testing for null pointers before use: `if (a != 0 && a->b != 0 && a->b->c != 0) { somefunc(a->b->c->d); }`.  The sequence is critical to avoiding core dumps.  (And I'm ignoring the Law of Demeter for the purposes of exposition!)

Comment: @Jonathan: I ignore it for the purpose of getting any work done!

Comment: These are not "comparison" operators.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, it's guaranteed, otherwise such operators would lose much of their usefulness.

***Important notice***: this is valid *only* for the builtin `&&` and `||`; if some criminal overloads them, they are treated as "regular" overloaded binary operators, so in this case *both* operands are *always* evaluated, and in unspecified order as usual. For this reason, never overload them - it breaks a hugely important assumption about the control flow of the program.

---

### Relevant standard quotations

#### Builtin `&&` and `||` have guaranteed short-circuit behavior

§5.14 ¶1

> Unlike `&`, `&&` guarantees left-to-right evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

§5.15 ¶1

> Unlike `|`, `||` guarantees left-to-right evaluation; moreover, the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to `true`.

#### If overloaded, they behave as "regular" binary operators (no short-circuit or guaranteed ordering of evaluation)

§13.5 ¶9

> Operators not mentioned explicitly in subclauses 13.5.3 through 13.5.7 act as ordinary unary and binary operators obeying the rules of 13.5.1 or 13.5.2.

and `&&` and `||` are not mentioned explicitly in these subclauses, so regular §13.5.2 holds:

§13.5.2 ¶1

> A binary operator shall be implemented either by a non-static member function (9.3) with one parameter or by a non-member function with two parameters. Thus, for any binary operator `@`, `x@y` can be interpreted
>   as either `x.operator@(y)` or `operator@(x,y)`.

with no special provision for evaluating only one side or in a particular order.

(all quotations from the C++11 standard)

Comment: By the way, keep in mind that, if you have "simple" conditions (e.g. your second one) branching can cost more than evaluating the condition itself.

Comment: Matteo Italia: `a` and `b` were hypothetical. They might've been `IsPrime(n)` and `IsEven(n)`, in which the right order is pretty obvious and serious savings can be made.

Comment: @nightcracker: sure, I was just pointing out a small but common misconception. :)

Comment: Conditions without side-effects can be moved anywhere the compiler likes. The compiler is allowed to eliminate a branch.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: it's _very_ important to note that if you override `operator&&` or `operator||` then it's treated like a regular function call, and the left-to-right evaluation is no longer guaranteed.[

Comment: @MooingDuck: yep, that's really important indeed; added the remark and the relevant standard quotations.