# Execution direction of && Condition

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logical comparisons: Is left-to-right evaluation guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683026/logical-comparisons-is-left-to-right-evaluation-guaranteed)

I have been taught that for every C function arguments, Rightmost argument will be executed/processed first and it progresses towards left.
Right part will be executed first and it progresses towards left.

Is this applicable to conditions like && and || ??

If I am writing a C++ Code, I check for NULL condtion first and then in next if I perform my action. for e.g.

```
 if( CommDevice != NULL)
   {
      if(CommDevice->isOpen == TRUE)
         { 
                //Do Something
         }

   }
```

Can I convert this in `if((CommDevice != NULL) && (CommDevice->isOpen == TRUE) )`

That "Code executes from Right to Left" fear is stopping me coz what if `CommDevice` is NULL and I am trying to access a member of NULL.  It will generate exception.

Comment: What you're showing is expression, not argument.

Comment: You can't count on function argument evaluation order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376278/parameter-evaluation-order-before-a-function-calling-in-c. That doesn't apply here, though, due to short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have been taught that every C function takes argument from right to left. Right part will be executed first and it progresses towards left.

This is 100% not true. The order of argument evaluation is unspecified!

The order of `&&` and `||` is defined because it forms a sequence point. First the left is evaluated, and if not short-circuiting then the right is evaluated.

```
if((CommDevice != NULL) && (CommDevice->isOpen == TRUE) )
```

This is correct.

Comment: I think he meant by "takes arguments from right to left" the order in which arguments are passed, in this case, generally speaking, yes, arguments are passed in reverse order on the stack.

Comment: Yes @mux, that's what I meant!

Comment: @mux I don't see how that's relevant as the order of evaluation, not passing, is what matters.

Comment: @Pubby what I meant is that he confused the order of evaluation with the order of passing.

Comment: @mux: The mechanism for passing arguments is also unspecified. Arguments passed in registers can't be said to be ordered at all.

Comment: Just one more detail: depending on the types of the arguments, it's *possible* to overload `operator&&` and/or `operator||` -- and when you do, it's a normal function call, the order of evaluation is unspecified. Needless to say, such overloads are rarely a good idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo that's why I said "generally speaking"  I wanted to add that it depends on the calling convention, but the point is I wanted to clear that for the OP.

Comment: @mux: I do not think he was confused. gcc for example evaluates from right to left. However it's formally unspecified and they could change the behavior at any time.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The OP said so himself, check the second comment. I know it's unspecified, that's not the point, I'm just saying he mixed passing arguments with evaluating arguments.

Comment: @mux: *Right part will be executed first and it progresses towards left.* => I think he clearly stated what gcc does. Though I suppose it does not matter so much either.

Comment: Relax guys! @mux You are right. I am updating question as @ Matthieu M. suggested.

Answer (score 3):

From the "`C Programming Language`" by Brian Kernighan & Ritchie Dennis (authors of C):

- "Expressions connected by && or || are evaluated left to right, and it is guaranteed that evaluation will stop as soon as the truth or falsehood is known."

I should point out that I once confused the order of evaluation rules for `&&` and `||` with the following in C:

```
x = f() + g();
```

Note that order of evaluation for `f()` vs. `g()` CANNOT be determined.

Comment: +1 for adding K&R reference!

Answer (score 0):

`&&` evaluates from left to right, not right to left! So your code will NOT throw any exception.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the logical operators are concerned, you're touching on [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

It is safe to check for the `NULL` pointer first on the left, because if this condition returns false, then the next condition of the `&&` (from left to right) is not evaluated.

This behavior is allowed because of the basic logical principles of `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 0):

Order of evaluation of functions arguments is `Unspecified` .So whatever you have been taught is not according to language standard.

Regarding your code :

The order of evaluation of `&&` and `||` is specified and this is `Left to right`

And this also follows the short-circuit of statement 
In case of `&&` if 1st is `false` then rest of the conditions will not be executed.
Similar in `||` if 1st is `true` then rest of the conditions will not be executed.

And also `&&` and `||` are sequence points.