# Why does this do/while never end?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, do-while

It just keeps looping. The numbers continue decreasing until the program is closed. Am I misusing something?

The playerHealth and orcHealth ints are 100.

```
randomNumber = ("%10d", 1 + (rand() % 100));
```

This was the way I seen the random number used on an srand() explanation page. If this is wrong, how should it be?

Are there any other problems here?

```
    switch(charDecision)
{
case 1:
    cout << "FIGHT" << endl;
    do{
        randomNumber = ("%10d", 1 + (rand() % 100));
        if(randomNumber >= 50){
            orcHealth = orcHealth - (randomNumber - (randomNumber / 5));
        cout << "You hit the orc! He now has " << orcHealth << " life left!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            playerHealth = playerHealth - (randomNumber - (randomNumber / 5));
            cout << "The orc hit you! You now have " << playerHealth << " life left!" << endl;
        }
    }while(playerHealth || orcHealth >= 0);
    break;

default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: Well, the `rand` call *does* have modulus bias. I recommend making use of `<random>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition for the `do...while` statement will stop at some point, but only at some point. This means, your condition will be met if either `playerHealth` is zero or `orcHealth` is smaller than zero. What if the `playerHealth` gets below zero? This is very likely since you are always deducting a number from both character's healths. A possibility of `playerHealth` becoming exactly zero is a very tiny one. And when the `playerHealth` goes below zero, its possibility of becoming zero is still very unlikely, even due to integer overflow. So, if you want to "kill" the character when one of their health becomes zero or less, you better change that line with something like

```
while ( playerHealth > 0 && orcHealth > 0 )
```

On a side note, the `||` statement works if *any* one of the statements is true. In C++, for an integer a `0` value is false, all other values -including negative ones- are treated as true. Also, the `||` checks from left to right and when it finds the first `true` statement, it stops searching. In your case, it checks `playerHealth`, which is very likely nonzero. When it sees this expression is true, it decides that the whole statement inside the parantheses is `true` and skips checking `orcHealth >= 0`. This results in the infinite loop. You might want to look at the order of evaluation of conditionals in `C++`, [maybe something like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683026/logical-comparisons-is-left-to-right-evaluation-guaranteed).

Answer (score 17):

`playerHealth || orcHealth >= 0` does **not** mean "while playerhealth greater than zero OR orchealth greater than zero". It means "while playerhealth, cast to boolean is true OR orchealth greater than zero".

Comment: i.e player health needs to be exactly 0 to evaluate to false, good catch

Answer (score 8):

This

```
}while(playerHealth || orcHealth >= 0);
```

should probably be

```
}while(playerHealth > 0 && orcHealth > 0);
```

I think you want to exit the loop, if either one is 0 or less.

Also, change `randomNumber = ("%10d", 1 + (rand() % 100));` to `randomNumber = 1 + rand() % 100;`
The comma operator just obfuscates the code.

Comment: `}while(playerHealth > 0 || orcHealth > 0);` is what he wanted, i guess.

Comment: @fiscblog you think the fight should continue until both are dead?

Comment: That could work. The fight stops when both are zombies, because zombies team up. :)

Comment: @hvd undead orc zombies woot! now that's an idea