# Alternatives to using boolean variable to enable next step of program to progress (without early return)

Tags: c++, function

I have several steps in a function, if a step fails, I don't want to execute the following steps. I also would like to only have one return statement. one option is nested if-else but that gets nasty so I won't even put an example here.

What I've been doing is something like this (assume `step_n` functions return bool):

```cpp
bool my_function()
{
   bool succeeded;

   succeeded = step_1();

   if(succeeded)
   {
      succeeded = step_2();
   }

   if(succeeded)
   {
      succeeded = step_3();
   }

   ...

   if(succeeded)
   {
      succeeded = step_n();
   }

   return succeeded;
}
```

This seems like the best case I can think of, but when the function does not return bool and I have to do an additional check each function call, things can get very repetitive and ugly.

Any modern c++ ways to accomplish this same idea?

Comment: Use exceptions. Only catch an exceptions if the code can recover from them.  This approach leave above the code looking like `step_1(); step_2(); step_3(); ... step_n();` No `if`  tests and no need to return a result.  Every function either works or throws.

Comment: @RichardCritten using exceptions for non errror conditions, especially to control program flow,  is a classic anti patern

Comment: @pm100 I think I misunderstood the question.  If `step_x()` fails I read this as being an error condition.

Comment: If failure typically doesn't occur when the program operates normally, it should be reported as exception. This is entirely depending on the use case, e. g. a disk failure is exceptional for regular programs, but can be considered the normal case for a disk repair program.

Comment: In my case, a failed step would indicate an "error condition". This was not in my original post, but this is in an environment where we are not using typical exceptions for error handling, but this does seem like the most logical approach in that case. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is equivalent to what you show.

```
bool my_function()
{
   return step_1() &&
          step_2() &&
          step_3() &&
   ... 
          step_n();
}
```

It's not "modern" though.  Any version of C++ can do this.

Comment: Love it, this has the simplicity I need. For other's looking here. [`&&` execution is guaranteed left-to-right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683026/logical-and-or-is-left-to-right-evaluation-guaranteed), which is why this works. The only downfall would be if more than one statement was needed in each `if` block. But that was not a part of my original question.

Comment: @cam.b if more than one statement were needed in a single condition, put the statements in a lambda that returns the appropriate `bool`.

Comment: great idea! That would do it for me then.

Answer (score 2):

(puts on fire protective clothing)

```
  bool func(){
     bool success = false; 
     if(!func1()) goto out;
     if(!func2()) goto out;
     if(!func3()) goto out;
     success = true;
    out:
     return success;
   }
```

Comment: (holds [Jiffy Pop](https://www.jiffypoppopcorn.com/) nearby...)

Comment: How to use early exit without using early exit.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be memory-inefficient, but not very error prone:

```
auto const steps =
std::to_array<std::function<bool()>({
    [&]{/*TODO:step_1 instructions*/},
    [&]{/*TODO:step_2 instructions*/},
    //TODO: more steps...
    [&]{/*TODO:step_n instructions*/}
});

for(auto const& f:steps)
    if (!f());
       break;
```

You can also use `std::find_if` - instead of raw `for` loop - to count the executed steps:

```
auto step_count=distance(
     begin(steps),
     std::find_if(
          begin(steps),
          end(steps),
          [](auto const & f)/*->bool*/
            {return !f();}));
```

required std header files are:

```
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
```